# Writing data to text file using BCP prompts for file storage type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I'm copying data from SQL to text file using bcp tool with following command:

```
    bcp.exe "exec <StoredProcedure>" queryout "temp.txt" -T -r\n -c
```

This command runs as expected on test environment and creates/updates required file without additional prompts.

But when it's run in client's environment, bcp additionally prompts for field length, prefix and field terminator- so when command is run from SQL Agent job, it get's stuck in infinite wait.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Based on [bcp documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), when -c parameter is used - it shouldn't prompt for type, etc. and should use char as the storage type, with no prefix, and \t as field terminator.

Comment: I would guess the somewhere between your test environment and the client's environment's actual execution of the command that the "/n" is somehow getting turned into a real new-line.  Try putting the "-c" before the "-r" and see what happens.

Comment: the `-r\n` is redundant `-c` means the same as  `-t\t -r\r\n` so either use the one or the other

Comment: @RBarryYoung, your guess turned out to be correct, it solved the issue. Thanks. Would be good if you move your comment to an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Jasper Schellingerhout, it really is redundant, thanks for a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the somewhere between your test environment and the client's environment's actual execution of the command that the "/n" is getting turned into a real new-line. Try putting the "-c" before the "-r" and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to specify the record delimiter, so remove the `-r\n`. The `-c` option will use tab for columns and carriage return and line feed for records (same as specifying `-t\t -r\r\n`). Otherwise like the other poster stated, make sure the `-c` is specified first

Side note: I recommend that as a practice (not as a solution) that you output the format file using `-f"yourpathandfilename.fmt"`. On the client side you use the `-f` param with import as well. This way if there is a difference between the source and target you can manually tweak the format file.